# Horizontally scrolling Grid Lists?

Tags: android, android-layout

There are a lot of questions on here asking about horizontally scrolling GridViews.   A few have answers that lead to some custom classes that manage to do it, yet Google clearly indicates there a standard way to do this.  They have [an entire page about it in their Design section: Grid Lists](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/grid-lists.html). This page illustrates horizontally scrolling grids and implies strongly that this is normal, supported behavior (as it should be).  They go into great detail about WHEN to use it. Unfortunately, they neglect to mention HOW to do it.  I have searched all day to find an example of how this is accomplished with GridView or any other standard Android UI class, regardless of SDK version.  Is their documentation wrong?  What is this page referring to?

Comment: Have you looked into horizontalscrollviews before? perhaps you can put a gridview inside one of these ; http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> yet Google clearly indicates there a standard way to do this

No, they do not.

> They have an entire page about it in their Design section: Grid Lists.

They have material in the Design section for which there is no out-of-the-box implementation in the Android SDK. Other examples include the [drawer](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html), some of the [gestures](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/gestures.html), and [section headings in lists](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/lists.html).

> Is their documentation wrong?

It is design documentation. To that extent, it is not "wrong" to have a design that calls for a horizontal-scrolling `GridView`. The mere fact that the Android SDK does not supply one -- at least at the time of this writing -- does not preclude somebody creating one.

> What is this page referring to?

Grids.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the other mythical beasts in their Design guidelines.  The vast majority of this Design section is directly supported via the SDK. I find it curious that they recommend UI behavior that requires rather complex custom classes to pull off.

Answer (score 0):

try an xml with the following;

```
<HorizontalScrollView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<GridView
    //your layout
     >
</GridView>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Actually, I did.  Other questions on here suggest that but I have been unable to actually make that work.  

Besides, at best, won't that simply force a fully-rendered, yet mostly off-screen GridView that defeats some of the efficiency of it?